# Use spark mapPartition function to iterate over dataframe row and add new column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I'm new to spark and scala. I was trying to use `mapPartitions` function on a Spark `dataframe` to iterate over `dataframe` rows and derive a new column based on the value of another column from the previous row.

Input Dataframe:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+
|   order_id |person_id | create_dt |
+------------+----------+-----------+
|          1 |        1 | 2020-01-11|
|          2 |        1 | 2020-01-12|
|          3 |        1 | 2020-01-13|
|          4 |        1 | 2020-01-14|
|          5 |        1 | 2020-01-15|
|          6 |        1 | 2020-01-16|
+------------+----------+-----------+
```

From above dataframe, I want to use `mapPartitions` function and call a scala method which takes `Iterator[Row]` as a parameter and produces another output row with new column `date_diff`. The new column is derived as the date difference between `create_dt` column of current row and previous row

Expected output dataframe:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   order_id |person_id | create_dt | date_diff |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|          1 |        1 | 2020-01-11|        NA |
|          2 |        1 | 2020-01-12|         1 |
|          3 |        1 | 2020-01-13|         1 |
|          4 |        1 | 2020-01-14|         1 |
|          5 |        1 | 2020-01-15|         1 |
|          6 |        1 | 2020-01-16|         1 |
+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Code I tried so far:

```
// Read input data
val input_data = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1,"2020-01-11"), (2,1,"2020-01-12"), (3,1,"2020-01-13"), (4,1,"2020-01-14"), (5,1,"2020-01-15"), (6,1,"2020-01-16"))).toDF("order_id", "person_id","create_dt")

//Generate output data using mapPartitions and call getDateDiff method
val output_data = input_data.mapPartitions(getDateDiff).show()

//getDateDiff method to iterate over each row and derive the date difference
def getDateDiff(srcItr: scala.collection.Iterator[Row]) : Iterator[Row] = { 
  for(row <- srcItr){ row.get(2)} 
/*derive date difference and generate output row*/ 
}
```

Could someone help me on how to write the `getDateDiff` method to get the expected output.

Comment: Not sure why do you wanted to use mapPartiions here, there are wildly used and more performant functions available already in spark function stack.would recommend to use - `date_diff($"create_dt".cast("date), lag($"create_dt".cast("date), 1).over(Window.partitionBy("person_id")))`

Comment: Hi @SomeshwarKale, I was trying to repartition the input data and then want to derive the column. So using ```mapPartitions``` will perform the transformation across all the records in a partition instead of calling the derivation across each record. I think ```lag``` will perform at each record and if the records for a given person are spanned across multiple partitions then it will take more time to shuffle the data and perform the transaformation. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: whatever optimization you are trying to achieve, i think that is already there in `lag` over given window. Why can't you implement the solution i suggested and check the execution plan? just to verify, check spark UI too for the number of tasks run